# Save jwt to local storage

Tags: node.js, authentication, jwt, frontend, pugjs

I'm currently developing a node express postgresql application, and I'm trying to implement Jsonwebtokens as authentication. I've seen multiple tutorials on how to implement it and I get how to do it on the backend part, but the frontend is usually skipped and apparently everyone just tests their code with Postman.

I have also read online that the recommended way to implement jwt authentication is to store the generated token in localstorage, and, when needed, to send it on the header. But I wasn't able to find how this is done...

Thus, my questions are:

1. How do you store the token on the front-end once it's generated by the backend? (an example would help a lot, because I don't really get how am I supposed to get the token on a front-end javascript program)
2. How do you send the token on the headers when making an http request that needs it once you have it stored?

Comment: You can use cookies, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573223/set-cookie-and-get-cookie-with-javascript

Comment: @MevlütÖzdemir Cookies are no longer the recommended option, that's why I'm trying to do all this... but thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

On the server side, once you have created the token and logged the user in, you send the token via res.send(), example below, note that you may have different approach to functions findByCredentials ad genereateAuthToken, they are custom:

```
app.post("/users/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findByCredentials(
      req.body.email,
      req.body.password
    );
    const token = await user.generateAuthToken();

    res.send({ token: user.tasks });
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).send();
  }
});
```

On the frontend you can use html5's fetch() to send the token in the header. For example, if you would like to access '/users/me' that needs authentication you follow the steps below (make sure you however you save the token to localstorage first so you can access that via getItem:

```
localStorage.setItem('userInfo', JSON.stringify(userInfo));

document.getElementById("my-profile").addEventListener("click", getMe);
```

then:

```
function getMe(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'));
    console.log(`Authorization=Bearer ${token}`)
    fetch('/users/me', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
        }
    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
            // window.location.href = 'http://localhost:3000/dashboard';
        })
        .catch(err => { console.log(err) })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said, usually the token is store in localStorage.

> localStorage is similar to sessionStorage, except that while data
>   stored in localStorage has no expiration time, data stored in
>   sessionStorage gets cleared when the page session ends — that is, when
>   the page is closed.
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

For getting the token in front-end you send to a URL the email & password of the user in order to exchange it with a token (you have to be in https). After that you store it with `localStorage.setItem('key', value)`

Short example:

```
$.post("/authenticate", {email: userEmail, password: userPassword}, function(data) {
  localStorage.setItem('token', data.token)
});
```

For get back the token, after a refresh for example, you have to use :  `localStorage.getItem('key')`.

And finally, in order to be authenticate with this token, you can send it in bearer headers in `Authorization` headers property.
Why bearer ? => https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/108662/why-is-bearer-required-before-the-token-in-authorization-header-in-a-http-re

Example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/account,
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + token
    }
}, function(data) { 
    // Authenticated data
});
```

May this can help : https://github.com/auth0-blog/angularjs-jwt-authentication-tutorial/blob/master/frontend/login/login.js

Comment: The example you give in your answer is setting http headers on an AJAX request, but is this possible to set headers when clicking on a navbar link? Or when submitting a form? Thanks a lot for your answer! It's helped me store the token in local storage! Now I just need to figure out how to send it when needed...

Comment: @Juan Did you ever figure this out? Currently still stuck on trying to figure out how to send the token.

Comment: @Scott Not really figured it out... I ended up using a cookie since I could not send the token from local storage when submiting a form. Sending the cookie in the headers and reading it on the server side was very standard and I had no problem after that.

Comment: @Juan Yes I used the same solution myself!